# Binding/corresponding text to numbers in sequence (SEQ) fields

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, list

**Background:**

In Word, I use 'SEQ' fields to create numbered lists throughout the document.

*For example*: (1) contains a table showing... while (2) contains a table showing...

Now, I sometimes need to refer back to these numbers in the text ("as we have previously shown in (2)"). The problem is that due to edits, the position of these items changes, which also changes the corresponding number (i.e. an item that was earlier #2 is now #3).

**The Question:**

How can I, in the text, reference these numbers when necessary, in an automatic manner, Meaning that I only have to designate the relevant number once, and it then the text automatically updates whenever the corresponding number changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **using cross-references together with bookmarks**:

1. Highlight the SEQ you want to reference.
2. Under the "Insert" tab, select "Bookmark" (and create a bookmark).
3. Then, in the location in the text where you want to reference the SEQ number, click "Cross-reference" (also under the "Insert" tab), select reference type "Bookmark", and insert the desired bookmark.

I found the solution a few minutes after posting. Credit goes to http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom/cross-referencing-a-seq-field/d7836117-f9b9-4cbf-ae04-12866ac88527

Comment: I don't think this works well, because you have to create a name for the bookmark, and then insert a reference to that new *name*, and not the current SEQ number, unless I've missed something. When you insert new SEQs, you'll mess up your names. Better, I think, to reserve a high-numbered heading for this purpose.